# Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView in Dialog

Tags: android, android-xml, androidx, classnotfoundexception, searchview

```
 <style name="WallSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/light_black</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/gray</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_12sdp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/inter_medium</item>
        <item name="android:cursorVisible">true</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    </style>



<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_gray_corner">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:theme="@style/WallSearchView"
                app:queryHint="Search for country"
                app:searchHintIcon="@null" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

> ```
> plugins {
>     id("com.android.application")
>     id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
> }
>
> android {
>     namespace = "com.inventoryManagement"
>     compileSdk = 34
>
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId = "com.inventoryManagement"
>         minSdk = 24
>         targetSdk = 34
>         versionCode = 1
>         versionName = "1.0"
>
>         testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>         vectorDrawables {
>             useSupportLibrary = true
>         }
>     }
>
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             isMinifyEnabled = true
>             isShrinkResources = true
>             proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android- optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro") }  }
>     compileOptions {
>         sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>         targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     }
>     kotlinOptions {
>         jvmTarget = "1.8"
>     }
>
>     composeOptions {
>         kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
>     }
>     packaging {
>         resources {
>             excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
>         }
>     }
>     buildFeatures {
>         dataBinding = true
>     }
>
> }
>
> dependencies {
>
>     implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
>     implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
>
>     implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
>     implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
>     implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
>     implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")
>     implementation("androidx.palette:palette-ktx:1.0.0")
>
>     implementation ("androidx.browser:browser:1.7.0")
>     // TODO Retrofit (Api Calling) lib
>     implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0")
>     implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
>     implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
>     implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0")
>     implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5")
>     implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5")
>     implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2")
>     implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2")
>
>     implementation ("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")
>     implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0")
>     implementation ("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
>     implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1")
>     implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0")
>     implementation("androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:8.2.1")
>
>
>     testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
>     androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
>     androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")  }
> ```

```
> to all sub-projects/modules. plugins {
>     id("com.android.application") version "8.1.4" apply false
>     id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.21" apply false
>     id("com.android.library") version "8.1.4" apply false } buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
>         google() 
> 
>  }
>     dependencies {
>         // Add this line
>         classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4")
>     } } 

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists
> distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
> zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME zipStorePath=wrapper/dists 

pluginManagement {
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         mavenCentral()
>         gradlePluginPortal()
>     } } dependencyResolutionManagement {
>     repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         mavenCentral()
>     } }
> 
> rootProject.name = "Inventory Management" include(":app")
```

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.inventoryManagement, PID: 4962
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46 in com.inventoryManagement:layout/common_list_layout: Binary XML file line #46 in
com.inventoryManagement:layout/common_list_layout: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46 in com.inventoryManagement:layout/common_list_layout: Error inflating class
androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:881)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1033)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:988)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1150)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1153)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:709)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:547)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:182)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.transitionTo(PhoneWindow.java:533)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:464)
at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:603)
at com.inventoryManagement.dashboard.activities.orders.AddOrdersActivity.onCreate$lambda$6(AddOrdersActivity.kt:154)
at com.inventoryManagement.dashboard.activities.orders.AddOrdersActivity.$r8$lambda$8qhvxEL1_ZQhbiVklZFEiQwfAUk(Unknown Source:0)
at com.inventoryManagement.dashboard.activities.orders.AddOrdersActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7745)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7722)
at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:854)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29111)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8319)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #102 in com.inventoryManagement:layout/abc_search_view: Binary XML file line #102 in
com.inventoryManagement:layout/abc_search_view: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #102 in com.inventoryManagement:layout/abc_search_view: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0303ac a=-1}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1001)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:985)
at android.view.View.(View.java:5811)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:225)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:220)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:73)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:233)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:152)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
AndroidRuntime                  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1024)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:988)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1150)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1153)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1153)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:709)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:547)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:290)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:276)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:881)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1033)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:988)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1150)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1153)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:709)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:547)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:182)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.transitionTo(PhoneWindow.java:533)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:464)
at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:603)
at com.inventoryManagement.dashboard.activities.orders.AddOrdersActivity.onCreate$lambda$6(AddOrdersActivity.kt:154)
at com.inventoryManagement.dashboard.activities.orders.AddOrdersActivity.$r8$lambda$8qhvxEL1_ZQhbiVklZFEiQwfAUk(Unknown Source:0)
at com.inventoryManagement.dashboard.activities.orders.AddOrdersActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7745)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7722)
at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:854)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29111)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8319)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)

Comment: Please include the `WallSearchView` style in your question.

Comment: Yes sure updated @AbdullahJaved

Comment: The issue seems to be with your `SearchView` style compatibility. Removing the theme property from `SearchView` should fix your crash.